# Visual Studio Code and php

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phplint

Is it possible to use phplint and phpcs with Visual Studio Code editor?
It seems that it's possible with Visual Studio Code tasks, is it right? If yes, how?
[Visual Studio Code Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic example of a PHPLint task for Visual Studio Code. It isn't very sophisticated, but you will see that it gets things working.

A more sophisticated Regular Expression is needed to properly identify which lines are errors, which are warnings, and which don't matter at all.

```
{
    "command": "C:\\phplint\\phpl.bat",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "args": [
        "C:\\Code\\index.php"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": {
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*):(.*)$",
            "message": 1
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a custom problem matcher to parse the output of PHPLint. The pattern has a regexp, which parses the output of PHPLint, followed by a list of what is in each position (in this case, I am just treating the whole line as a "message" - a bit too basic, but you get the idea).

This is essentially how you would create a task for anything you can access on the command line.

Comment: Is it possible use lint in current file instead of value for args that you used?

Comment: A more sophisticated regex and task: https://github.com/ikappas/vscode-phpcs/issues/28#issuecomment-517370358 ( I couldn't get it to work, but maybe someone else can )